# C# Javascript/Jquery Onclick Button Anchor-ID

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, anchor

The purpose is to click a website button from Code.
It's works well while the element has an ID.

Example:
HTML Code:

```
<span class="button" id="button-id" data-spm-anchor-id="1234.00000000.000000">Text</span>
```

C# Code:

```
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('button-id').click()");
```

But, in few section in the code the buttons doesn't have an Unique ID only anchor ID.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-spm-anchor-id="1234.00000000.0000000.1">Text</a>
```

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: You could probably find an element with an anchor Id via jquery and click that, but personally I'd simply ensure the buttons have a unique id.  I'd also probably be doing client-side stuff in client-side JS anyway, rather than injecting bits of code from the server side like this.  It's not so clear to see what's going on...

Comment: Is there any reason to use ExecuteScriptAsync rather than just simply writing the JS code in a regular `<script>` tag? Anyway, you can select elements by their other attributes, not just their ID, it's easy to find examples if you google. Or, presumably you can modify the HTML so the relevant buttons have IDs?